# How can i play modal video(React video player on pop up) onClick event of a particular video in React.js

Tags: reactjs, video-player

I have multiple videos emended in my Component. All i need to do is, once i click on/play a particular video, a pop up should appear playing that video with all the controls in reactjs.

Comment: Show your components/ setup, so that we can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using react portals and you can select the video to be played by using state.

[React portals](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html)

[React useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)

if you have the videos themselves stored or even if you have just the URLs for the videos. While showing the multiple videos you must have used an array/object you can replicate the selection.
This should ideally be the structure of your app.
The root component(one where the modal pops up) should have the state and the callback(on
select function) which should be passed on to the component that renders multiple videos.
Each of these videos must call the on select function on click(or whichever event handler you want to use) then turn a boolean true in the root component and render the video based on it

EDIT:
I believe I didn't help with picking a particular video. For the same when you are rendering them as a list(I'll refer to that component as VideoList and to each Video as VideoItem)
You'll be having a root component(referred to as App) and you can have the following structure:

```
App
    CallbackFuncToSelectVideoAndUpdateState(selectedVideo){

    }
    VideoModal//(initially set it as null or don't render anything using a boolean)
    VideoList
        VideoItem onClick=(item)=>CallbackFuncToSelectVideoAndUpdateState(item) id=videoItemId
```

VideoItem.js

```
handleClick(props.id){
    props.onClick(props.id)
}
return <div onClick=handleClick><otherComponentStructure/></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.... Is there any other way where i can achieve the same functionality? Or if possible can you share the code snippet

Comment: Since it's dev I don't think there are less than 10s of ways to do this. I would use this particular design since it seems relatively optimal and readable. Is there any issue with this particular setup?
As far as writing code is concerned, you can try out writing code for this method and then update your question(or ask a new one and tag me) at any point you are stuck and I'll be happy to help out

Comment: The only thing i am concerned with is how can i play a particular video onclick event of that video only. In my case it is picking the last videourl of the array only(once i click on any video)